# How do I return the new count of record?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, mysqli

I have a notification functionality, and it updates in the table when read/viewed.
What i have is a list of li of the notifications & when the button was clicked it calls the ajax function to mark it as read, however my problem is how can I update the counter in the page since it count only for the notifications that wasn't read yet.
my js code is here:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {
    $(".confirm").click(function() {
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
        var parent = $(this).parent();

        var closest_li = $(this).closest('li');

        $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "mark_read.php",
           data: dataString,
           cache: false,
           beforeSend: function() {
                closest_li.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300).animate({ opacity: 0.35 }, "fast");;
           }, 
           success: function() {
                closest_li.slideUp('fast', function() {$(this).remove();});
          }
         });
        return false;
    });
});
```

And here is the file content of the mark_read.php

```
    <?php
if(isset($_POST['id'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $id = mysqli_real_escape_string( connect(), $id );
    $result = query("UPDATE tbl_notifications SET log_stat='1' WHERE log_id='$id'");
}
?>
```

and my counter is a label that echoes the php sql query of count num rows.

Comment: After your `UPDATE` query, you could do a `SELECT` query to get the new number, sending the value back, and in your `$.ajax::success` do an update using the value.

Comment: how can I do that in the
$.ajax::success

Comment: look at the docs - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ - you can capture the return data in `success: function(data){ ...}`, note, `data` is an example and can be named anything - `data`/`response`/etc. So if the `data` is returned as the number of unread, you could do something like `success: function(data){ closest_li.slideUp('fast', function() {$(this).remove();}); $('#unreadNumber').html(data); }`, where you set the unread number to the new returned number.

Comment: @Sean These should probably be an answer. You clearly helped the user here, you should get reputation for it.